# Jquery Populate dropdown from other

Tags: jquery

I am populating drowpdown from another dropdown value. Everything is fine for the first time but when i again change the first dropdown the previous values are still showing in second dropdown. Following code i am using to populate second dropdown!!

```
<select id="NextSession" name="NextSession">
<option value="1">Coffee</option>
<option value="2">Tea</option>
</select>

<select id="NextSectionId" name="NextSectionId">
<option><option>
</select>

$("#NextSession").blur(function() {
$("#NextSectionId").load("/GetData/" + $("#NextSession").val());
});
```

Here is my php code:

```
$UniqueId=$_GET['UniqueId'];
$query2="select ClassName,SectionName,SectionId from class,section where class.ClassId=section.ClassId and class.ClassStatus='Active' and section.SectionStatus='Active' and class.Session='$UniqueId' order by ClassName";
$check2=mysql_query($query2);
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($check2))
{
$SelectClassName=$row2['ClassName'];
$SelectSectionName=$row2['SectionName'];
$SelectSectionId=$row2['SectionId'];
echo "<option value=\"$SelectSectionId\">$SelectClassName $SelectSectionName</option>";
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem!!

Here is the live example!!

myraipur.com/test/test.php

select any option in first dropdown, choose from second...then go for first and the 2nd dropdown remains as it is!!!

Comment: Try doing this:

    `$("#NextSession").change(function () {
        $("#NextSectionId").load("/GetData/" + this.value);
    });`

Comment: still facing the same problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the `bur` callback to `change` and before make the new request clear all old values.

Something like this:

```
$("#NextSession").change(function() {
  $("#NextSectionId").empty();
  $("#NextSectionId").load("/GetData/" + $("#NextSession").val());
});
```

Some external links:
[jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
[jQuery.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: i have tried html,empty,clear,reset all the function!!! but none of them are working!!!

Comment: yes getting the exact data from server everytime i change the dropdown...but the previous result is also included in new result!!!

Comment: Try this: `$("#NextSectionId li").remove();` insted of `$("#NextSectionId").empty();`

Comment: Can you put a live example for us check what is happening?

Comment: `$("#NextSectionId").load("/GetData/" + $("#NextSession").val(), function(response, status, xhr) {
  alert(response);
  alert(status);
  alert(xhr);
});`

Comment: http://myraipur.com/test/test.php

select any option in first dropdown, choose from second...then go for first and the 2nd dropdown remains as it is!!!

Comment: The problem don't appear to be with the HTML select (dropdown). The problem appears to be in plugin that you use to change the select default aspect. Try to reset plugin when clear select elements. What plugin you use?

Comment: Try change your script to this: `var cSelect; 
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#CurrentSectionId").select2(); 

 $('#CurrentSectionId').select2({placeholder: "Select"}); 

 cSelect = $("#Student").select2(); 

 $("#CurrentSectionId").change(function() { 
  cSelect.val(""); 
  $("#Student").load("test2.php?UniqueId=" + $("#CurrentSectionId").val()); 
 }); 
});`

Comment: Try now: `var cSelect; 
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#CurrentSectionId").select2(); 

 $('#CurrentSectionId').select2({placeholder: "Select"}); 

 cSelect = $("#Student").select2(); 

 $("#CurrentSectionId").change(function() { 
  cSelect.select2("val", "");
  $("#Student").load("test2.php?UniqueId=" + $("#CurrentSectionId").val()); 
 }); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the second select before loading content

```
$("#NextSession").blur(function() {
  $("#NextSectionId").html(''); //emptying select field
  $("#NextSectionId").load("/GetData/" + $("#NextSession").val());
});
```

Comment: Check if the data returns only content of selected value i.e 1 or 2

Comment: The issue has to be from server side. Try to do a print_r of the array returned.

Comment: getting the exact data from server everytime i change the dropdown...but the previous result is also included in new result!!!

Comment: When you say "the previous result is also included in new result", are you talking about just the select box content(UI) or the array returned itself has previous result?

Comment: i am talking about the select box content!!! the result from the server is correct everytime...but the select box has the previously selected values!!!

Comment: Oh strange. Can you try `$.ajax` instead of `.load()` and on success add the data to the select?